# More RegEx problems - UK phone numbers - Bash

Tags: regex, bash, phone-number

I'm having yet more problems with my RegEx,
This time, i have to ask a user to enter their phone number then check it is correct.

i have tried the following:

```
if [[ "$number" =~ ^[\(]?[\+44,0][1-9][0-9]{3}[\)]?[\ ]?[0-9]{6} ]]
then
    echo "YEP"
else
    echo "NOPE"
fi
```

I've also had a mess around with slightly varying the RegEx...

this seems to work with numbers like:

```
07384323455
(01273)277364
01677 336482
```

But not with any numbers with the `+44` in it...

Is there anything i am doing terribly wrong or anything anyone can suggest?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Have a look at the explanation created for your regex here: http://regex101.com/r/gT5oT8 - you'll quickly see your errors.

Comment: Having two 4s in the same character class is equivalent to having one 4 in the character class (i.e. `[ .... ]` is a character class). Not sure if you can solve this using shell reg-exs. Good luck.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the replies.. so i cant use the number +44786655433 for example? or can i change the [\+44,0] to work with this at all?? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try out this expression: `^(?:\((?:\+44\d{4}|\d{5})\)|\+44\d{3}|\d{5}) ?\d{6}$`

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/lC5kM6

Here's an explanation for your expression: regex101.com/r/gT5oT8 (try to figure out your errors)

Comment: Ahh, Thank you for this, so the `:` is basically marking the start of alternatives? 
also, i presume my mistake is in the `[\+44,0]` part which matches it wrong. - As you can tell, I'm quite new to this!

Comment: @Sam_Web: The (?:) construct is a non-capturing group. Check the demo, there's an explanation there!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#!/bin/bash
for number in '07384323455' '(01273)277364' '01677 336482' '+447384323455' '(+447384)323455' '+7384323455' '(+437384)323455'
do
    if [[ "$number" =~ ^[\(]?(\\+44|0){1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[\)]?[\ ]?[0-9]{6} ]];
    then
        echo "YEP"
    else
        echo "NOPE"
    fi
done
```

*Output*

```
YEP
YEP
YEP
YEP
YEP
NOPE
NOPE
```

**Explanation**

- `(\\+44|0){1}` - Matches the character sequence `+44` or `|` zero `0`, capture group matches exactly once.

Comment: This is wrong, `[\+44|0]` doesnt do what you think it does. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: Yeah, this does not work for `(+44####)######` - thanks @Lindrian